# Where should I be using data mappers while still keeping controllers thin in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, datamapper

If i'm trying to keep with my controllers thin, and my models unaware of the details of their persistance, where should I be saving/accessing my models?  I can't put it in the controller, and I can't put it in the domain object, is there supposed to be some other layer/object which handles this type of processing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [table gateways](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) in my controllers

```
$userTableGateway = new UserTableGateway();
$userTableGateway->getUser( 5 ); // returns a user object
$userTableGateway->insert( $user ); // Adds a new user
$userTableGateway->save( $user ); // Saves a user
```